# What should be done with this post offering a monetary reward?

Tags: discussion

I found [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038553/how-to-create-launchpad-ppa-from-ubuntu-binary). The OP states:

> A 30k Geek (GeekCash) reward is given to you after the job is complete.

I wasn't sure what this meant, so I commented:

> What does "What does a 30k Geek (GeekCash) reward is given to you after the job is complete mean?

The user replied with:

> Yes, you can download GeekCash Wallet at geekcash.org/#wallets and create a wallet address, after that I send coin to your address.

This confirms my suspicions. GeekCash is a cryptocurrency. **The user is offering real money in return for a solution.**

As [these](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6291/is-it-allowed-to-offer-something-not-a-bounty-in-exchange-for-an-answer) [three](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42767/should-i-edit-out-an-offer-of-financial-reward) [posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29008/how-do-you-respond-when-someone-offers-to-pay-you-on-so) (well not so much the last one but the first two anyway) say that **this is not OK**. Please could we have this edited out/deleted/something else to nuke this *real money* business?

Original comment:

[How to create Launchpad PPA from Ubuntu binary](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038553/how-to-create-launchpad-ppa-from-ubuntu-binary?noredirect=1#comment1691025_1038553)

Comment: *real* currency :/ which is oddly enough part of the question. Bit of a chicken and egg issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I removed the offer of remuneration.

Thanks for bringing this up, but next time just suggest an edit. There's no need for a meta discussion for something so easily fixed.

Comment: In my opinion asking for guidance here on meta is just fine - so I don't agree wholly with your statement.

Answer (score 4):

CVT'd  as spam.

He is pushing his own product.

Comment: I don't see why it's the OP's product. All we need is a simple edit as far as I can tell.

Comment: @terdon probably because https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=3695071.0 is one of the top results if you google this thing (see usernames) Also one of the other top results is https://codequs.com/p/S1xTXF-RM/geekcash-launching (identical content to the previous link), and this user's profile says they work at codequs

Comment: @muru yes, but they did not link to it in the post, did not try to push it or anything else. All they did was ask a question about something they need for work and added a misguided offer of remuneration. I removed the offer, but see nothing spammy. Can we not ask questions on AU if they are related to our work now?

Comment: @terdon looks like we disagree, but if someone were to start a new cryptocurrency and then offer that very same cryptocurrency as reward for doing something on a post about something related to that cryptocurrency on AU, that'd feel like a poorly disguised attempt to increase usage of that cryptocurrency, and hence spam, to me.